# Scrape and post results on my website

Tags: automation, web-scraping

I want to place a code on my website that will scrape the price of a product on another website then place the result on my website automatically. My website host does not support PHP. Is their away to do this? Maybe with JavaScript or a third party library? Checked google but could not get any answers, would really appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: Javascript as language can do that, however due to same-origin policy you won't be able to scrape pages from other domains that where the page loading javascript is.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this options with perl. Almost every server in the world supports perl.

[perl web scraper in google](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl%20web%20scraper&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

If that is too complicated, check this other links with tutorials

- [Basic PHP Web Scraping Script Tutorial](http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scrape-tutorial/basic-php-scraping.php)
- [PHP Web Page Scraping Tutorial](http://www.devblog.co/php-web-page-scraping-tutorial/)

Bye

Comment: I checked out perl but can't really understand how to implement it. Does the code go on the website or on a program on my computer? If on a program I download on my computer how does it get to my website through ftp? kind of a newbie would appreciate some simple steps thanks.